# How to stop PyCharm from populating docstrings?

Tags: python, intellij-idea, pycharm, docstring

If I add a docstring to a method using the triple-quote, as soon as I type a space after the triple-quote, PyCharm will populate the docstring with the parameters the method takes, and a return value, like so:

```
def fill_blank(self, direction):
    """ 
    :param direction: 
    :return:
    """
```

I've searched the PyCharm preferences for "docstring" and "stub" and turned off everything that shows up, even if it doesn't seem to pertain to this particular behavior; and I've googled high and low, but can't figure out how make it stop.  Does anyone know how?  (This is in PyCharm CE 3.4)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to set the docstrings format to "Plain". It defaults to reStructuredText, which is giving you those hints.

The setting is found under Python Integrated Tools in your project settings.

1. File > Settings
2. Python Integrated Tools
3. Docstring format

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Thanks!  I had unchecked the checkbox, but would never have thought to change the type.

Comment: Hmm -- since the 2016 release, this is the default behavior. In fact, there seems to be no way to turn it on.

Comment: user48956, did you ever find an answer to this?  I'm trying to get the old docstring behavior back as well, but can't get it to work on Pycharm professional 2016.  Seems like a bug.  I love that feature

Comment: Go to settings->Editor->General->Smart Keys-> and uncheck "Insert pair quote"

Comment: user2682863, you're a life saver.  I haven't been able to get PyCharm to insert the docstring template for months.  Unchecking 'Insert Pair Quote' fixed it.  Much appreciated.

Comment: Different path for Version 2019.3. File/Settings/Tools/Python Integrated Tools