# How to enable python docstring insertion in 2016.1 Intellij IDEA/Python Community Edition 5.1.145.45

Tags: python, intellij-idea, pycharm

IDEA's python plugin used to helpfully insert docstring stubs for function definitions after typing out the function definition in Python. However, since a recent update, no luck. Also ALT+ENTER, doesn't provide the option in the dropdown to insert a doctring stub :(

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098863/how-to-stop-pycharm-from-populating-docstrings) shows how to disable this behavior in older versions. I havn't modified this setting or turned anything off in:
File > Settings > Python Integrated Tools > Docstring format

I also installed IDEA+PyCE on a new machine - same behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move your cursor right after the `def` keyword. Then press `AlT+ENTER`, select `insert documentation string stub` from the dropdown that appears.
[image: Move cursor to position right after <code>def</code> keyword]
[image: Press ALT+ENTER]